# Javascript data-attribute isArray returns true

Tags: javascript

So as im building a small plugin I can across a small issue, when filtering the selectors I check if the selector is an Array, which in most cases works but when using a attribute(dataset in this case) it sees the selector as an array.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
    var Constructor = function (selector) {
        if (!selector) return;
        if (selector === 'document') {
            this.nodes = [document];
        } else if (selector === 'window') {
            this.nodes = [window];
        } else if(typeof selector === 'string') {
            this.nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        }else{
            this.nodes = Array.isArray ? selector : [selector];// it will return as an array
        }
    };

partofanplugin.find('[data-id="12"]')// will be seen as an array instead of a string.
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually call the function, right now you are just checking if the function exists

```
Array.isArray(selector) ? selector : [selector];
```

instead of

```
Array.isArray ? selector : [selector];
```